# Buttons in Unity (2022.3.4f1) not working, probably something with eventsystem

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the current Unity project i'm working on I have a canvas set up with an eventsystem. Childed to the canvas I have a button that I ant to be able to press. I have looked up a bunch of tutorials and nothing worked. But then I discovered that the eventsystem doesn't take inputs (tried removing and creating a new one). Normally it should show a bunch of input such as "Pointer:", "delta" etc. I have tried creating a new empty scene with button etc that still doesn't work. My only lead is an error message I get but I can't see the difference between the not working project and the functioning project.

ArgumentException: Input Button Submit is not setup.
To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input
UnityEngine.Input.GetButtonDown (System.String buttonName) (at :0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseInput.GetButtonDown (System.String buttonName) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/BaseInput.cs:126)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ShouldActivateModule () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/StandaloneInputModule.cs:227)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:503)

As I didn't find a problem to try to fix I have almost tried nothing expect creating the new project.

I'm pretty new to Unity and appreciate any help that could help me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the `EventSystem` object in your scene, if you see a message like this:
[image]

Simply click on the `Replace with InputSystemUIInputModule` button.
This will change the input module to use the new input.

You can also replace the input module by removing the `Standalone Input Module` component and using `AddComponent` to add the `Input System UI Input Module`.
[image]

Comment: @DetVarInteJag I added the manual way of switching the input module component, hopefully that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76725261/7111561)

In general if using the new input system there is the default actions asset which contains some default actions - in particular a `UI` action map which is also by default pre-configured as the actions in the `InputSystemUIInputModule` on the `EventSystem`

[image]

If using a custom asset I would usually copy over the `UI` action map into my custom actions in order to have all in one place.

Comment: My eventsystem looks like the top picture but I don't have the button. Is there a way I can manually change to the new input system. But in the testproject  were the button works also have the old inputmanager so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: But it may help

Comment: What I meant with "Normally it should show a bunch of input such as "Pointer:", "delta" etc." was that in the inspector it has "Selected:" no module

Comment: Just remembered that I changed the editor version from Unity 2021.3.23f1